# Rewrite part of a url with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having an issue where a part of the url is being added when a search is made on my site. I am trying to use .htaccess to fix this.

The url that is being created is

```
www.mysite.com.au/search?q=teachers&Itemid=101
```

The issue is the `&Itemid=101`, ideally I could just remove it, another option would be changing it to `&Itemid=102`

I only want to trigger this rule when the url starts with `search?q=` as that is required for the search to work. I have crashed my router twice with my efforts and thought it may be safer to ask.
Let me know if this isn't clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(q=[^&]+)&Itemid=101(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(search)/?$ /$1?%1&Itemid=102 [L,R=301,NC]
```